# What web chat app could suit my specific needs?

Tags: web-apps, chat, web

I want to have a live chat on my website, with the following functionality:

- authorization for users (via FB or email)
- ability to moderate users
- (ban or kick them out) ability to have a bot, who would post ads on
  specified time-frames
- maybe an additional position for ads or something

Is there a solution for this need? It can be paid of course